# Calling QStandardItem mimeData() method

Tags: qt

In my app I have a `QTableView` and a `QTreeView`. I need to drag from the table view and drop in the tree view.  I had this working, but I reworked the app so that the GUI elements were created in C++ and this this has stopped working.

I can pick up an item from the table and drop it on the tree - all looks fine. However, the table model's `mimeData()` method is not called, so the dropped data is incomplete.

How do I get the drag drop operation to call the `mimeData()` method?

The tables' model is based on a `QStandardItemModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with my code. Make sure you override the mimeData properly. For example, some examples show the prototype as:

```
QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> &items) const;
```

while the correct prototype is:

```
QMimeData * mimeData(const QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items) const;
```

(note the missing reference in front of items). And if you implement it incorrectly, you're not overriding the mimeData() but implementing another mimeData() function.

An easy check to make sure you're doing it right is to declare a function you want to override, but change its return type from QMimeData* to bool, such as:

```
bool mimeData(const QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items) const;
```

If you are overriding a correct function, your code will not compile due to conflicting return type (you're not allowed to override only the return type). If your code compiles fine, you are not overriding anything but instead declaring a new function. Check the function signature.